# How do I add iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission to a service account?

Tags: python, google-speech-api

I am trying to deploy a Django website which works locally on my development machine but does not work on my VPS.

I have followed the guide https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc#how-to to run this command:
gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account SERVICE_ACCT_EMAIL

I enter my authorisation code as expected and it seems to work.

However when I try to run my python app non locally I get this error message:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 403,\n    "message": "Permission \'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",\n    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",\n    "details": [\n      {\n        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",\n        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",\n        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",\n        "metadata": {\n          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n')
(learndutch) splat@ourvps:~/learndutch
```

I am presuming I somehow need to grant the iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission to my Service Account but I don't know how to.  I have tried asking Gemini Google AI bot for advice but none of the solutions work their either.

I think the easiest solution, if possible, is to show me the Cloud CLI command to grant iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken to my service accout but I have no idea what syntax is required and I find the documentation confusing and seems to apply only to Google Workspaces.

Please advise.

Thanks